# Loop over Regex to extract columns by multiple name-value combination

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a dataframe with column names like `v1,...,v99, tm1,...tm99` and so on. Not for every number exists a column though (mybe v42 is missing). The letters can vary from a to `zzz`. I have written a method to filter my columns according to a letter combination (like `'v'` or `'tm'`) followed by a figure. This looks like

```
def create_required_dataset(df, var_filter):
    persDf = df.filter(regex=('^' + var_filter + r'[0-9]+$'))
    return persDf
```

This works `create_required_dataset('v')` and I receive a dataframe with all columns starting with `v` followed by a number.

and works fine. But now I have to deliver not only one letter combination `(`'tm', 'zzz'`)` but as many  as the user puts in.

So the query should look like:

```
create_required_dataset('v', 'tm', 'zz')
```

What I have tried is to work with `*args` so I have rewritten my method to

```
def create_required_dataset(df, *args):
    persDf = df.filter(regex=('^' + args + r'[0-9]+$'))
    return persD
```

But this does not work, even if I transform the `tuple` into a `list`. Obviously since the `regex` only takes one `string`. I thought about a Lambda-Apply Method that applies the regex function but could not get this to work as well. I just have no idea how to accomplish this now and need some help. I

Comment: Try `'^(?:{})[0-9]+$'.format('|'.join(args))` instead of `'^' + args + r'[0-9]+$'`

Comment: `df[ [col for col in df.columns if ('v' in col or 'tm' in col or 'zz' in col)] ]` should return only columns containing those letters.

Comment: Wiktors solution works for me. Thank you very much! Please write a solution so I can confirm it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use an alternation based pattern, just wrap the alternatives with a non-capturing group

```
persDf = df.filter(regex=('^(?:{})[0-9]+$'.format('|'.join(args))))
```

This will create a regex like `^(?:v|tm|zz)[0-9]+$` that means:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:v|tm|zz)` - any of the alternatives: `v`, or`tm`, or`zz`
- `[0-9]+` - 1+ digits
- `$` - end of string.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fmaaMb/1) and [its graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(%3F%3Av%7Ctm%7Czz)%5B0-9%5D%2B%24):

[image]